# How to show the unique name and URL of a each choropleth popup in Leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm fiddling with the Leaflet [choropleth example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html), trying to have a popup that shows each state's name and its own URL which are written in the varStates json.

In my local example, I put each state's name and URL as properties, but I can't get the .bindPopup to reference the props in the json. It can just show text enclosed in "".

My example is in: jsfiddle.net/yLa4acvy/1/

I tried something like

```
    .bindPopup( props.name + "<br> <a href='localhost/'" + props.url_id + "'>This company</a>")
```

But couldn't get it to work, even if I create new vars for the properties and reference those.

**EDIT:** I found a mapbox solution, though I would still like to know how to do it in leaflet:  https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/custom-marker-tooltip/

Comment: To bind a popup to every feature in your geojson, you must add layer.bindPopup( props.name + "<br> <a href='localhost/'" + props.url_id + "'>This company</a>") inside your click event function, and not to the geojson itself

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment before, you'll have to bind the popups inside onEachFeture function, something like this:

```
L.geoJson('data', {
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        layer.on('click', function() {
            //you bind the popup here, you can acces any property of your Geojson with feature.properties.propertyname
            layer.bindPopup('<p>' + feature.properties.name + '</p><p>' + feature.properties.density + '</p>').openPopup();
        });
    }
});
```

Here's an updated JSFiddle demonstrating this:
http://jsfiddle.net/yLa4acvy/2/